# How to add a goal in Google Analytics based on the fragment identifier?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

I want to add Goal in Google Analytics with the same URL twice with a different values such as

```
www.example.com/checkout#shipping
www.example.com/checkout#payment
```

these are on the same page with different tabs. So how can I track which tab the user goes to?  Currently google analytics just tracks my checkout page, not which tab based on the `#shipping` and `#payment` fragment identifiers.

Comment: I added the term "fragment identifier" to your question because that is the technical name for the portion of the URL from the `#` to the end.